# what does a topological ordering have to do with a topology?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

I just read about topological orderings:

> "A topological ordering of a directed graph is a linear ordering of its vertices such that for every directed edge uv from vertex u to vertex v, u comes before v in the ordering."

**Why is this called a "Topological" ordering? What does it have to do with a topology on a set?** It is not obvious to me.

Comment: As far as I can tell, "topological ordering" has nothing to do with topology.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition for this has always been the following: "Topology" means something more general than the word as it is used for topological spaces. When talking about a graph, its topological properties refer to something like the 'shape' of the graph, in vague terms. You might have come across this as the phrase "network topology". (Note that a lot of the shape of a graph can actually be interpreted topologically: every graph can be turned into a CW-complex with zero-cells for nodes and 1-cells for edges -- but directedness is not something that carries over directly.)

This is (arguably non-conclusively) backed up by [this answer to the same question on tcs.se](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30659/why-is-topological-sorting-topological).